# Google Auth with Google Drive using python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-api, google-drive-api

I am working with google api's with google authentication to access google drive. And it always showing me an error. and has a message "You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API."

even though i already add all scopes needed.

[image: code][image]

Comment: Hi could you provide what `user type` did you used in your `Oauth Consent Sceen`? Under `APIs & Services` in your cloud console

Comment: hello thank you so much for the reminder. in my case i only forgot to add user types. thank you so much!